# Stop wordpress from hardcoding img width and height attributes

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I'm wondering if there's a simple way top stop WordPress automatically hardcoding featured image height and width attributes, other than using regex...

As I'm using a flexible grid for my project (who isn't!) this is causing some funky image issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get featured image URL and add it to your content manually, eg:

```
<?php 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' ); 

if ($image) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: only works for hard coded wordpress pages, which is useless for a CMS.

Comment: Keep in mind:
This method prevents responsive images since WP 4.4 because it doesn't includes the `srcset` attribute.

Answer (score 14):

You can remove the width and height attributes by filtering the output of `image_downsize` function found at `wp-includes/media.php`. To do this, you write your own function and execute it via your theme's functions.php file or as a plugin.

**Example:**

Remove the `width` and `height` attributes.

```
/**
 * This is a modification of image_downsize() function in wp-includes/media.php
 * we will remove all the width and height references, therefore the img tag 
 * will not add width and height attributes to the image sent to the editor.
 * 
 * @param bool false No height and width references.
 * @param int $id Attachment ID for image.
 * @param array|string $size Optional, default is 'medium'. Size of image, either array or string.
 * @return bool|array False on failure, array on success.
 */
function myprefix_image_downsize( $value = false, $id, $size ) {
    if ( !wp_attachment_is_image($id) )
        return false;

    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
    $is_intermediate = false;
    $img_url_basename = wp_basename($img_url);

    // try for a new style intermediate size
    if ( $intermediate = image_get_intermediate_size($id, $size) ) {
        $img_url = str_replace($img_url_basename, $intermediate['file'], $img_url);
        $is_intermediate = true;
    }
    elseif ( $size == 'thumbnail' ) {
        // Fall back to the old thumbnail
        if ( ($thumb_file = wp_get_attachment_thumb_file($id)) && $info = getimagesize($thumb_file) ) {
            $img_url = str_replace($img_url_basename, wp_basename($thumb_file), $img_url);
            $is_intermediate = true;
        }
    }

    // We have the actual image size, but might need to further constrain it if content_width is narrower
    if ( $img_url) {
        return array( $img_url, 0, 0, $is_intermediate );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Attach the new function to the `image_downsize` hook:

```
/* Remove the height and width refernces from the image_downsize function.
 * We have added a new param, so the priority is 1, as always, and the new 
 * params are 3.
 */
add_filter( 'image_downsize', 'myprefix_image_downsize', 1, 3 );
```

Also don't forget to scale the images correctly in your CSS:

```
/* Image sizes and alignments */
.entry-content img,
.comment-content img,
.widget img {
    max-width: 97.5%; /* Fluid images for posts, comments, and widgets */
}
img[class*="align"],
img[class*="wp-image-"] {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images with WordPress-added height and width attributes are scaled correctly */
}
img.size-full {
    max-width: 97.5%;
    width: auto; /* Prevent stretching of full-size images with height and width attributes in IE8 */
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Cheers,

Comment: This removes `srcset`, `sizes` and other responsive image attributes unfortunately. :( This is my current sollution, that rebuilds the attributes back: https://gist.github.com/cibulka/8e2bf16b0f55779af590472ae1bf9239

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `post_thumbnail_html` filter to remove the attribute:

```
function remove_img_attr ($html) {
    return preg_replace('/(width|height)="\d+"\s/', "", $html);
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_img_attr' );
```

Place this in your `functions.php` file

Comment: Still works like a charm.

Comment: This is the best answer i've found

Answer (score 6):

You can overrule inline styles/attributes with `!important`:

```
.wp-post-image {
    width: auto !important; /* or probably 100% in case of a grid */
    height: auto !important; 
}
```

It's not the cleanest solution, but it solves your problem.

Comment: For some reason the class `wp-post-image` wasn't included in my images. Instead I had something like `wp-image-26`. I had to use another selector but the idea worked.

Comment: Indeed @Pier, use the @marsandback answer below, particularly with the includes attribute selector, `img[class*="wp-image-"]`. No need for `!important`!

Answer (score 3):

**CSS solution:**

```
img[class*="align"], img[class*="wp-image-"] {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

This allows responsive images to work as they should, meanwhile you maintain the width and height attributes in the img element, which is probably better for older browsers, performance and/or to pass HTML validators.

**PHP solution:**

This will prevent the addition of width/height attributes on any newly-added media in the WP editor (via 'Add Media'). FYI, it may affect your image captions too!

```
function remove_widthHeight_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}

add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_widthHeight_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_widthHeight_attribute', 10 );
```

Comment: THIS is the best solution for Wordpress, because it fixes too large pictures within a table in the editor, preventing you from scrolling horizontally. Apply it to front and admin area!

Answer (score 2):

**Best solution is to place jquery in footer**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('img').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
});
```

Comment: Any explanation about why this is the "best" solution?

Comment: because sometimes "add_filter" don't work where you want it to be that's why I said

Answer (score 1):

Add this piece of code: (Applies to new Gutenberg editor too)

```php
function disable_add_img_width_height( $value, $image, $context, $attachment_id ) {
    if ($context === 'the_content' || $context === 'the_excerpt' ||  $context === 'widget_text_content')
        return false;
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'wp_img_tag_add_width_and_height_attr', 'disable_add_img_width_height', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Just wondering - is there a reason for filtering on the context?

Comment: @JamesSnell of course, well, it depends on the context... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Javascript solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('img').each(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('width')
  $(this).removeAttr('height');
 });
});
</script>
```

This can be used to target specific images instead of all images by using a CSS selector, like so:

```
 $('.myspecificclass img').each(function()
```