# Remove height attribute from wp_get_attachment

Tags: images, customization

I found this great solution: [Stop wordpress from hardcoding img width and height attributes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29881/stop-wordpress-from-hardcoding-img-width-and-height-attributes)

But I was wondering if I could do it only in one specific case and not in all the site because it messes up other stuff. This would be the case:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'six', false, $default_attr); ?>
```

Removing only height but not width in all the site would also work.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? Understanding your need may open up other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
function remove_width_and_height_attribute( $html ) {
   return preg_replace( '/(height|width)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
}
```

and then change

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
```

to

```
remove_width_and_height_attribute(wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' ));
```

Comment: Instead of removing the width and height, you could also make them more useful by making a proper `style` attribute for them. Even though that's not what the OP asked, it will make the page less "jumpy" if there are lots of images to load: `return preg_replace('/ width="(\d*)" height="(\d*)" /', ' style="width:$1px;height:$2px;" ', $html);`

Comment: inline style is generally considered a bad idea. Both for maintenance sake and speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the data for width and hight of a image.

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' );
var_dump($src);
```

the `var_dump` output like this:

```
array
  0 => string 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/DSC00261.JPG' (length=63)
  1 => int 1632
  2 => int 1224
  3 => boolean false
```

The results mean:

```
$src[0] => url
$src[1] => width
$src[2] => height
$src[3] => icon
```

Answer (score 0):

**One** specific case and not in all the site.

**Fx.** If you want to remove width="400" from WordPress a HTML output function, you could do this:

**Somewhere in a file:**

```
ob_start(); // Start buf
wp_get_attachment_image($imageID, 'full', false); //'full' = size
$htmlString = ob_get_clean(); // output to variable
echo preg_replace('/width="\d*"/','',$variable); // Remove width attribute and whatever digit inside.
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done.