# How do I remove inline style in featured image markup?

Tags: theme-development, css, post-thumbnails

When I create featured images, the markup that wordpress produces has inline css. The image tag for the image has width and height parameters.

This is very frustrating: I'd like to control the image style with my own css.

How can I remove the inline style?

Comment: Take a look to [answer][1] of mr Jiang


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115717/14536

Comment: Inline height and width __attributes__ can be overridden from a stylesheet.

Comment: No they can't. That's not how css works. Inline style overrides stylesheet rules.

Comment: Width and height attributes are not an inline style so @s_ha_dum is correct. By default WordPress doesn't put inline styles on images so if there is a style attribute it is added by your theme or plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wp_get_attachment_image_src which will return the image url using the thumbnail ID

```
<img src="<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'full'); echo $image[0];?>" />
```

Comment: out of all the answers on this page, this appears to be the cleanest solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Inline CSS will always take priority over any CSS in the stylesheet unless you're peppering your CSS with !important's and/or mile-long selectors - which is bad practice. Try checking out this other question which has the solution, [Filter to remove image dimension attributes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/filter-to-remove-image-dimension-attributes).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You set the featured image sizes in your functions file:

```
add_image_size( 'featured-image', 300, 100, TRUE );
```

Then you can style the featured image from your style.css file.

Or you can over ride the default using CSS.

```
.wp-post-image { 
 your declarations
 }
```

Change the class for your featured image to match your theme.

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter called [`post_thumbnail_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/) which allows you to modify the html of the featured image just before it is returned from [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/). You can simply do a search and replace on this html string to remove unwanted attributes. Like this:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse117447_remove_atts' );

function wpse117447_remove_atts ($html) {
    $html = preg_replace ('/(width|height)="\d+"\s/', "", $html);
    return $html;
}
```